# Why is the discriminant of an algebraic number field an invariant?

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $n=[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}]$ and let $A$ be the matrix with $a_{ij}=tr_{\mathbb{Q}(a)/\mathbb{Q}}(a^ia^j)$ where $a_{ij}$ is the $ij^{\text{th}}$ entry and $0\leq i,j\leq n-1$. Then the discriminant of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ is the image of $\det(A)$ in $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}/{\mathbb{Q}^\times}^2$. Why is the discriminant of a number field an invariant? If $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ are isomorphic, why does that imply that their discriminants are the same?

Comment: Where did you find this construction? This isn’t what is usually understood by “the discriminant of an algebraic number field”…

Comment: Hint: replace $(a^i)_i$ by *any* $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$. What happens?

Comment: There are two versions of the discriminant, one works for any finite separable field extension, but only gives an element modulo squares in the base field. The other one is more specific to number fields, uses an integral basis and gives an actual integer.

Comment: @Aphelli If the discriminant with respect to one basis is $x$, and the discriminant with respect to another basis is $y$, then $x=\det(C)^2y$ where $C$ is the change of basis matrix. Now if $Q(a)$ and $Q(b)$ are isomorphic, then that isomorphism $T: Q(a)\rightarrow Q(b)$ must fix $\mathbb{Q}$ pointwise (because it sends 1 to 1, and then -1 to -1, so it sends $a$ to $a$ for any integer $a$, so it sends $m/n$ to $m/n$ for any integers $m$ and $n$). So if we replace the transition matrix $C$ with matrix representation of $T$ (with a nice choice of basis), we get that $x=det(T)^2y$, where $x$ is

Comment: @Aphelli the discriminant of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ with respect to the basis chosen for $T$ in the domain and $y$ is the discriminant of $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ relative to the basis chosen in the codomain.